# Where is the notification in the app when a post of mine is edited?

Tags: bug, ios-app, notifications, global-inbox

Today in the app I was told I had three unread messages in my inbox but I only saw two:

> [image]

This is because the “answer edited” message only shows up on the website:

> [image]

Can this be fixed?

- App Version: 1.6.6.2
- Device: iPhone SE
- OS Version: Version 11.4.1 (Build 15G77)